# Two external CSS ID's but only first one works

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an external CSS for my table.  It has alternating shaded rows.  I want one table cell to have a green background and red font.  Another cell to have a red background with green writing.  But it will only take the first ID.  If I put the red background first, that will show but not the green.  If I put the green background first, that will show but not the red.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black; text-align:center;
}

 #worst {font-style:bold; background-color: red; color:green };
 #best  {font-style:bold; background-color: green; color:red };
```

html

```
<tr>
  <td>Hummer</td>
  <td>290</td>      
  <td>115</td>
  <td ID="worst">405</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Bike</td>
  <td>0</td>        
  <td>5</td>
  <td ID="best">5</td>
 </tr>
```

Is that a property of external CSS's or is something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bit subtle here, see the semicolons at the end of these lines of code?

```css
#worst {font-style:bold; background-color: red; color:green };
#best  {font-style:bold; background-color: green; color:red };
```

Those should not be there. What's happening is that when you put a semicolon where it is, the CSS parser tries to read that. But it's a syntax error, so it skips the rest of your code because it assumes it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-colons should be inside the `}`, not outside it. You are creating an invalid selector `;\n #best`
(`\n` being a newline, of course!)